# Apply style to "i"th node, if "i" appears in a list of pairs

Tags: tikz-pgf, xparse

I have written a command to make the following image with TikZ:

[image]

Calling the command that created this image looks like this:

```
    \drawmatching{%
        G,A,T,T,A,C,A}{%
        G,C,A,T,T,G,C,A%
    }{
        0/0,
        1/2,
        2/3,
        3/4,
        5/6,
        6/7%
    }
```

This says to link position 0 in the first image with 0 in the second, position 1 in the first image with 2 in the second, etc.

Now what I'd like to do is style each of the letters that is at the end of an edge by, for instance, making it bold (or red, or whatever). That is, in the top string, I'd like letters at indices 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, and 6 to be bold, and in the bottom string, I'd like the letters at 0, 2, 3, 4, 6, and 7 to be bold. And this is where I'm stuck.

Here is the full MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}

\begin{document}


\newcommand{\letterspacing}{.5}


\NewDocumentCommand{\drawmatching}{m m m O{0} O{0}}{
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\xstart}{#4}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\ystart}{#5}

    \foreach [count=\i] \letter in {#1}{
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\index}{\i-1}

        % check if \index in the list of pairs?
        \tikzset{letter/.style={}}

        \node[anchor=base, letter] at (\xstart+\letterspacing*\i,\ystart) (a\index) {\texttt \letter};
        \node[above=.45cm, anchor=base] at (\xstart+\letterspacing*\i,\ystart) {\tiny \index};

    }


    \foreach [count=\i] \letter in {#2}{
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\index}{\i-1}
        \node[anchor=base] at (\xstart+\letterspacing*\i,\ystart-2) (b\index) {\texttt \letter};
        \node[anchor=north] at (\xstart+\letterspacing*\i,\ystart-2) {\tiny \index};
    }

    \foreach \i/\j in {#3}{
        \draw (a\i) -- (b\j);
    }
}


\begin{tikzpicture}
    \drawmatching{%
        G,A,T,T,A,C,A}{%
        G,C,A,T,T,G,C,A%
    }{
        0/0,
        1/2,
        2/3,
        3/4,
        5/6,
        6/7%
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

My first thought was to check at the commented line above whether `\index` appears as the first number in a pair in the list of ordered pairs, but I fell down an xparse rabbit hole. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach with LaTeX conditionals and style commands. The idea is to do a nested loop over `#3` each time a letter needs to be printed, and in that nested loop check if any of the numbers mentioned in `#3` (first number for the top, second number for the bottom) matches the current index.

If a match is found (using `\ifnum[index from inner loop]=[index from outer loop]`), a command can be defined (called `\letterstyle` in the code below) to change the font, for example use a color, or italics, etc. This command should be assigned a default value before the loop that will be used if no match is found for any element in the loop.

Note that I switched `\texttt` to `\ttfamily` in your code, `\texttt` is a command that takes an argument, while `\ttfamily` is a switch that changes the font for all remaining text in the current scope (or until a new family is used with another font switch).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}

\begin{document}


\newcommand{\letterspacing}{.5}


\NewDocumentCommand{\drawmatching}{m m m O{0} O{0}}{
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\xstart}{#4}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\ystart}{#5}

    \foreach [count=\i] \letter in {#1}{
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\index}{\i-1}

        % default style if no match is found: black
        \gdef\letterstyle{\color{black}}
        \foreach \lfirst/\lsecond in {#3}{
            \ifnum\lfirst=\index\gdef\letterstyle{\color{red}}\fi
        }
        \node[anchor=base] at (\xstart+\letterspacing*\i,\ystart) (a\index) {\ttfamily\letterstyle\letter};
        \node[above=.45cm, anchor=base] at (\xstart+\letterspacing*\i,\ystart) {\tiny \index};

    }


    \foreach [count=\i] \letter in {#2}{
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\index}{\i-1}
        % default style if no match is found: italics  
        \gdef\letterstyle{\itshape}
        \foreach \lfirst/\lsecond in {#3}{
           \ifnum\lsecond=\index\gdef\letterstyle{\upshape}\fi
        }
        \node[anchor=base] at (\xstart+\letterspacing*\i,\ystart-2) (b\index) {\ttfamily\letterstyle\letter};
        \node[anchor=north] at (\xstart+\letterspacing*\i,\ystart-2) {\tiny \index};
    }

    \foreach \i/\j in {#3}{
        \draw (a\i) -- (b\j);
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \drawmatching{%
        G,A,T,T,A,C,A}{%
        G,C,A,T,T,G,C,A%
    }{
        0/0,
        1/2,
        2/3,
        3/4,
        5/6,
        6/7%
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Great! This is exactly what I was looking for. I had tried a similar approach, but with `\newcommand` and `\renewcommand`s inside the nested loop, but of course the result was forgotten due to how the loop works. I'll have to read more about global defs. Thanks!